# How to increase ajax request timeout length in a fluxible fetchr application?

Tags: javascript, fluxible, fetchr

I'm using yahoo's fluxible and fetchr and I get occasional timeouts in the request service calls.  How can I increase the ajax request timeout time in my configuration?

https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-plugin-fetchr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on looking at the lib code:

```
app.plug(fetchrPlugin({
    xhrPath: '/api',
    xhrTimeout: 2000
}));
```